# How to fix Failed to fetch platform cordova-ios@~4.4.0

Tags: ios, cordova, npm

When I use the "cordova platform add ios" command for the latest Cordova version which is 7.0.1, I receive a failed to fetch message.

I am trying to upgrade an existing project to iOS version 4.4.0 but for my peace of mind, I tried creating a fresh project which also had the same error.

Here is my terminal output below showing the errors I receive, can anyone recommend a solution to resolve this issue?

```
Stuarts-MacBook-Pro:T Stu$ cordova create myApp org.apache.cordova.myApp myApp
Creating a new cordova project.
Stuarts-MacBook-Pro:T Stu$ cd myApp
Stuarts-MacBook-Pro:myApp Stu$ cordova platform add ios
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@~4.4.0
Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-ios@~4.4.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Failed to get absolute path to installed module
Stuarts-MacBook-Pro:myApp Stu$ cordova platform add ios
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@^4.4.0
Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-ios@^4.4.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 254 Error output:
npm WARN org.apache.cordova.myapp@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Darwin 16.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.2.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "cordova-ios@^4.4.0" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9
npm ERR! path /Users/S/Development/T/myApp/node_modules/.staging/xml-escape-d330e1e1
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/S/Development/T/myApp/node_modules/.staging/xml-escape-d330e1e1' -> '/Users/S/Development/T/myApp/node_modules/cordova-ios/node_modules/xml-escape'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have resolved this, it appears to be an NPM issue and not a Cordova one. I just updated NPM within Terminal and after the update "cordova platform add ios" worked fine. Happy days - 1 !

```
npm update -g
```

Comment: Nice try but no cigar

Answer (score 4):

1. Delete the folder `cordova-ios`, located in `node_modules/cordova-ios`.
2. Type the following command

   ```
   ionic cordova build ios
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes a previously added Platform is not removed Properly, so this type of issue occurs. Remove the platform by command and add it again..

Follow this steps:

1. Run the command

   ```
    ionic cordova platform remove ios
   ```
2. Run the command:

   ```
    ionic cordova platform add ios --save
   ```
3. If you are **still getting the issue**, try running again:

   ```
    ionic cordova platform remove ios --save
   ```

**NOTE:** By running again the command `ionic cordova platform remove ios --save` fetches newer version of ios platform.
For example:

- First time: `cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@~4.5.1`
- Second time: `cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@~4.5.4`