# Can't add iOS platform to ionic app, Mac OS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to add iOS platform to my ionic 1 app but I get errors. How can I go further to build my app?

```
$ cordova platform add ios --save
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@~4.3.1
(node:14587) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to fetch platform cordova-ios@~4.3.1
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 254 Error output:
npm WARN @ionic-native/globalization@3.14.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/globalization@3.14.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/globalization@3.14.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN The package gulp is included as both a dev and production dependency.

npm ERR! path /Users/louisro/Documents/BoardLine/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansistyles
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/louisro/Documents/BoardLine/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ansistyles' -> '/Users/louisro/Documents/BoardLine/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.ansistyles.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/louisro/.npm/_logs/2018-04-16T21_04_03_502Z-debug.log
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/platform/addHelper.js:312:25
    at _rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:797:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:823:30
    at Promise.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:1142:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:808:41)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:176:11)
(node:14587) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14587) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my app",
  "app_id": "bc689f",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "newIonic: An Ionic project",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ionic-native/globalization": "^3.2.0",
    "@ionic/cloud": "^0.9.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.4.6",
    "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase": "~6.1.2",
    "cordova-android": "~6.2.3",
    "cordova-ios": "~4.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-admobpro": "~2.29.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "~0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "~1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "~1.0.7",
    "cordova-plugin-datepicker": "https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker.git",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "~1.1.6",
    "cordova-plugin-extension": "~1.5.1",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "~1.9.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "~2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-globalization": "~1.0.7",
    "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": "~1.8.2",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "~5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "~1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "~2.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "~1.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "~5.1.8",
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "ionic-app-lib": "^2.2.0",
    "ionic-plugin-deploy": "~0.6.7",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "~2.2.1",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "~2.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.4.0",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-gulp": "1.0.1",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic1": "2.0.0",
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-replace-task": "^0.11.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0",
    "yargs": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    {
      "locator": "https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker.git",
      "id": "cordova-plugin-datepicker"
    },
    "ionic-plugin-deploy",
    "cordova-plugin-extension",
    "cordova-plugin-admobpro",
    "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information",
    "cordova-plugin-compat",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-globalization",
    "cordova-plugin-google-analytics",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    {
      "id": "cordova-plugin-facebook4",
      "locator": "cordova-plugin-facebook4",
      "variables": {
        "APP_ID": "3996261696416",
        "APP_NAME": "my app"
      }
    }
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "android@6.1.0",
    {
      "platform": "android",
      "version": "",
      "locator": "android"
    }
  ],
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {},
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://@bitbucket.org/linedevs/myapp.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/linedevs/myapp#readme",
  "cordova": {
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ],
    "plugins": {
      "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase": {
        "BILLING_KEY": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAiqWZvb/CV3MWjSvTwRXrD3lt2BG8BGMoFjz8ZyBTkc"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-admobpro": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-compat": {},
      "cordova-plugin-console": {},
      "cordova-plugin-datepicker": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-extension": {},
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "___",
        "APP_NAME": "my app"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Line wants to offer the best experience."
      },
      "cordova-plugin-globalization": {},
      "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "com.googleusercontent.apps.10ji"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
      "ionic-plugin-deploy": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {}
    }
  }
}
```

And my ionic info:

```
$ ionic info
[WARN] Error with ./www/lib/ionic/version.json file: FILE_NOT_FOUND, trying 
       ./bower.json.

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 
    Gulp CLI              : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1

local packages:

    Cordova Platforms : none
    Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.2

System:

    Node : v9.11.1
    npm  : not installed
    OS   : macOS Sierra

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : /home/louis/android-sdk-linux/

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Comment: I think you need to install Cordova

Comment: Cordova is installed : `$ cordova -v` gives : 
`8.0.0
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this did the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45491459/2217647
updating npm allowed `$ cordova platform add ios` to work.

Answer (score 4):

First update the NPM

```
$npm update -g
```

then remove and add ios platform

```
$ionic cordova platform rm ios && ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command instead of just using cordova.

Use this command $ionic cordova platform add ios --save.

And try updating the node modules and npm